# EventTrigger is not working properly with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, caliburn.micro, eventtrigger

I have created EventTrigger for checkbox check and uncheck event which is placed  inside Grid in one View( view model name :EventViewModel) which is using Caliburn.Micro mvvm.

Code:

> xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
>   xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SelectedFile_Checked">
    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding Name}"/>
    </cal:ActionMessage>
 </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

We have used **Conductor.Collection.AllActive** in MainHomeWIndowViewModel and activate EvenView by using below code

```
Items.Add(new EventViewModel());
```

Problem is when SelectedFile_Checked event triggering its always locating into MainHomeWIndowViewModel  and its not reaching into EventViewModel. It should be always locate into method(SelectedFile_Checked ) inside EventViewModel.

Any idea to solve this issue!

Comment: So you also have a SelectedFile_Checked method in your MainHomeWIndowViewModel? What's the DataContext of the CheckBox? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: @mm8 : No ,SelectedFile_Checked  method  is not in MainHomeWIndowViewModel. Its present In EventViewModel becaue checkbox is in EventView. But instead of triggering event in EventViewModel its tying to trigger event  in MainHomeWIndowViewModel which is not present .